# Form in VB.net app that uses VLC Plugin causes error: Class is not registered

Tags: vb.net, plugins, vlc

I developed a desktop application using VB.net which makes use of the VLC Plugin to play videos.

It used to run on a PC until we had it reformatted. The application runs fine on my PC without any errors.

The error shows up whenever the form with the VLC Player needs to be shown. The error is as follows:

> See the end of this message for details on invoking  just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
>
> ************** Exception Text ************** System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred creating the form.
>   See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Class not
>   registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
>   ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154
>   (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid& clsid,
>   Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithoutLicense(Guid clsid)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithLicense(String license, Guid
>   clsid)    at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(Guid
>   clsid)    at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32 state)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible) 
>   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.EndInit()    at
>   sysQcf.FrmMediaPlayer2.InitializeComponent()    at
>   sysQcf.FrmMediaPlayer2..ctor()    --- End of inner exception stack
>   trace ---    at sysQcf.My.MyProject.MyForms.Create__Instance__[T](T
>   Instance)    at sysQcf.My.MyProject.MyForms.get_FrmMediaPlayer2()
>   at sysQcf.FrmLogin.login(String username, String password)    at
>   sysQcf.FrmLogin.TxtPassword_KeyDown(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyEventArgs(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyMessage(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmKeyChar(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>
> ************** Loaded Assemblies ************** mscorlib
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- sysQcf
>       Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
>       CodeBase: file:///D:/qcfupdated/debug/sysQcf.exe
>   ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.VisualBasic
>       Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 8.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Windows.Forms
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Drawing
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Runtime.Remoting
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Remoting/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- exampledll
>       Assembly Version: 2.2.2.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.1.1.0
>       CodeBase: file:///D:/qcfupdated/debug/exampledll.DLL
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Data
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Xml
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Configuration
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- Accessibility
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- AxInterop.AXVLC
>       Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
>       CodeBase: file:///D:/qcfupdated/debug/AxInterop.AXVLC.DLL
>   ---------------------------------------- Interop.AXVLC
>       Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
>       CodeBase: file:///D:/qcfupdated/debug/Interop.AXVLC.DLL
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Transactions
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.EnterpriseServices
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
>
> ### CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
>
> ************** JIT Debugging ************** To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this application or computer
>   (machine.config) must have the jitDebugging value set in the
>   system.windows.forms section. The application must also be compiled
>   with debugging enabled.
>
> For example:
>
> When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception will be sent to
>   the JIT debugger registered on the computer rather than be handled by
>   this dialog box.

I've tried registering VLC's dll (axvlc). I've included AxInterop and Interop .dll in my bin folder.  I can't register those because of an error. ActiveX is running in services.

I've been looking for solutions to no avail.

Comment: You need to install VLC Player.  That's what registers the appropriate COM components.

Comment: VLC Player is already installed on the PC I am trying to run it on. I'll try to reinstall it. Thanks.

Comment: @jmcilhinney apparently the guy installed 64-bit VLC. I tried intalled 32-bit VLC and it works now. Thank you

Comment: You would need a 64-bit version of your app to work with 64-bit VLC. In the project properties, if the target platform is `x86` or the target platform is `Any CPU` and the `Prefer 32-bit` box is checked then your app will run in a 32-bit process on 32-bit and 64-bit Windows. If the target platform is `Any CPU` and the `Prefer 32-bit` box is not checked then your app will run in a 32-bit process on 32-bit and in a 64-bit process on 64-bit Windows.